# Car steering issues

Tags: steering, gmc, steering-lock, acadia

I have a 2011 GMC Acadia SLE. I can move the steering wheel easily even though the car is off. I can even move the front tires with relative ease side to side. What could be the problem, if any? I mean the steering column should lock and be hard to move when car is off, right? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Do you know if your Acadia has electrically assisted steering, versus hydraulic?

Comment: I don’t know!! How can I find out? I do have a power steering fluid reservior!

Comment: If you have a power steering reservoir, then I doubt it is electrically assisted. I had a thought that if it continues even with the car off and it was electrically assisted, it might be powered on continually and therefor might be providing assistance at all times. It was an outside thought.

Comment: How easy is it?  Does it get easier when the engine is running and the vehicle is still stationary?